# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route' and webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am still running into errors with webapp2 and am at a lost what could be the problem here.

```
ERROR    2011-12-13 11:17:19,059 webapp2.py:1528] 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 526, in dispatch
    method_name = request.route.handler_method
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
ERROR    2011-12-13 11:17:19,060 wsgi.py:186]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 174, in Handle
    result = handler(self._environ, self._StartResponse)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/user/sdk/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 526, in dispatch
    method_name = request.route.handler_method
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Please note that I am using the latest SDK version (1.6.0) of GAE.

My code looks like this:

app.yaml

```
application: test-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.site_app
  login: required

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

main.py

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import webapp2
import urls

site_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(urls.SITE_URLS, debug=True)
```

urls.py

```
import webapp2

import handler

SITE_URLS = [
  webapp2.Route(r'/', handler.TestHome),
  webapp2.Route(r'/test/<test_key:\w+>', handler.TestPage)
]
```

basehandler.py

```
import os
import webapp2
from django import template

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.tdict = {}

  def render(self, template_file):
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                 'templates',
                                 template_file)
    t = template.Template(file(template_path,'rb').read())
    self.response.write(t.render(template.Context(self.tdict)))
```

handler.py

```
import os
from basehandler import BaseHandler

class TestHome(BaseHandler):

  def get(self):
    def get(self):
    self.render('browse.html')


class TestPage(BaseHandler):

  def get(self, test_key):
    self.tdict['test_key'] = test_key
    self.render('browse.html')
```

templates/browse.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Success!</title>
</head>
<body>
Success!
{% if test_key %}- {{ test_key }}{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is because you didn't call the `webapp2.RequestHandler.__init__()`. Here is a code snippet from [webapp2.py](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py):

```
class RequestHandler(object):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, request=None, response=None):
        self.initialize(request, response)
```

As you can see the `RequestHandler` is initialized with `request` and `response`. So you have to do same thing in your code:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        self.tdict = {}
        self.initialize(request, response)
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `initialize` in your own `__init__` - you should call the parent constructor with `super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(request, response)`. Always, always, always call the parent constructor.

Comment: @NickJohnson - that's not what [the webapp2 documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-init) says - does that need to be updated then?

Comment: @fishwebby My opinion is that the webapp2 docs are wrong. Subclasses should _always_ call the parent class's `__init__`.

Comment: @NickJohnson Agreed - I was doing it the other way in one of my apps because the documentation said that was the way to do it, but changing it to call the parent constructor works just as well (and is much better from an OOP perspective as you say)